# Regex - capture tagged template literal

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I need help building a regex to find all the tagged template literals in a js file

example:

```
const thing = test`
  background-color: red;
`;
```

regex result:

```
test`
  background-color: red;
`
```

I can accomplish this with:

`` (test`(?:[^`])*`) ``

the problem is I can't figure out how to exclude inner template literals.

For example:

```
const thing = test`
  background-color: ${show ? `red` : `blue`};
`;
```

expected regex match:

```
test`
  background-color: ${show ? `red` : `blue`};
`
```

actual match:

```
test`
  background-color: ${show ? `
```

any ideas?

Comment: ِDo they always end with `; entirely in a newline?

Comment: What about [`(test`(?:[^`]|`[^`]*`)*?`)(?=;)`](https://regex101.com/r/ocVl44/1)

Comment: @revo semicolons are not required at the end, so no - we can't expect that

Comment: Is the format always going to be such that the word "test" is followed by the `\``, then a new line, then the contents of the template literal, then another new line, followed by the final `\``?

`(test\`\n.*\n\`)`

Comment: @JaredASutton - alas no - the template literal is dynamic - the amount of lines is unknown

Comment: What would happen if the code you were searching contained ```var foo = /test`omg`/;```? Only a proper parser can tell that it's a regex with some text and not a tagged template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular Expression won't help you here, it is best to parse the JS file with an AST parser like `@babel/parser` - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-parser.html

Comment: that's where I'm leaning... regex just seemed like an easy solution without fiddling with a parser...